# Where to Add Main Method Java

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I have this code block which requires a main method in order to be run.

```
public class Point {

    private int xcoord;
    private int ycoord;

    public Point () {}

    public Point (int x, int y) {}

    public int getX () {
        return xcoord;
    }

    public int getY () {
        return ycoord;
    }

    public void moveUp(int amount) {}

    public void moveDown(int amount) {}

    public void moveRight(int amount) {}

    public void moveLeft(int amount) {}

}
```

I've tried adding in `public static void main(String[] args){` below `public class Point` but it causes problems throughout my program (saying Public Point () needs to be declared as new) and I close out the main method beneath the `MoveLeft` method closing colon and the `public class` Point closing colon, like this:

```
public class Point {

    private int xcoord;
    private int ycoord;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        public Point () {}

        public Point (int x, int y) {}

        public int getX () {
            return xcoord;
        }

        public int getY () {
            return ycoord;
        }

        public void moveUp(int amount) {}

        public void moveDown(int amount) {}

        public void moveRight(int amount) {}

        public void moveLeft(int amount) {}
    }

}
```

Comment: Your basic syntax is wrong. Main is a method, it should not contain other methods.

Just add main like you have added moveUp method in the class in second code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main is a method and you don't want your other methods to be inside of it.

Try something like this:

```
public class Point {

private int xcoord;
private int ycoord;

public static void main(String[] args) {

} //End of main

   //Now you add the rest of your methods
    public Point(){

    }

//And so on
```